# Getting rid of period and comma

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation

I am using apa.bst and want to know how to:

1) Get rid of the period after the year; and
2) Get rid of the comma after the journal title.

I currently have:
Baba, SA (1997). Democracies and inefficiency. Economics and Politics, 9(2):99–114.

I need it to be:
Baba, SA (1997) Democracies and inefficiency. Economics and Politics 9(2):99–114.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `biblatex` and more specifically `biblatex-apa`, as it is easy to customise. Here is an example where you'll find the lines of code to add to your preamble. Note that the syntax to produce a bibliography is somewhat different with biblatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,american, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

    \usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}


\begin{filecontents}{ashortone.bib}
@article{DroitVolet2007,
 author = {Droit-Volet, S. and Meck, W. H.},
 year = {2007},
 title = {{H}ow emotions colour our perception of time},
 pages = {504--513},
 volume = {11},
 number = {12},
 journal = {Trends in Cognitive Sciences}
}
\end{filecontents}

%%% add the following lines to your preamble

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
}
{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
}{}{}

    \addbibresource{ashortone.bib}

    \begin{document}
\nocite{*}

    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I modified your code but I odn't know if I did the right thing. However if you want to separate code blocks you can remove the percent signs

Comment: @percusse: It's perfect, thanks. I don't always think of checking the final result. The myriad of percent signs comes from a template in my editor, but you're right: they're unnecessary.